# Disable admin restrictions

Tags: cmd, administrator

My school has blocked literally everything on my windows laptop, I can't access cmd, gpedit.msc, regedit, setting/control panel and pretty much anything else you could think of that could disable admin restrictions. So how would i disable admin restrictions, i'm uses windows 10 (can find edition as info is blocked).i just need to be able to access one of the above mentioned things

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable "admin restrictions" if you are not part of the admins group.

The Administrator is the account who can change any configuration in your computer.

There is a group called "Administrators" those accounts can change any configuration in your computer too if they have the administrator role asigned to that group.

By default the first account in your PC is the administrator.

Check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14028/windows-7-how-log-on-as-an-administrator) for a better explanation.

Comment: Have you tried using Start->Switch user or Start->Log Off ?. I imagine that you have your credentials (username and password)

Comment: i dont know the admin password ive logged out thousands of times

Answer (score -1):

try opening cmd using powershell by typing

"start cmd"